# C# BotFrameWork Q & A Maker , Do you mean response?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, azure-qna-maker

When qna maker matches with multiple questions it responses with do you mean and list of questions? Is it possible to add alias for these questions , as the displaying the question user for training wont be appropriate.

Comment: Can you reformulate your question?

Answer (score 4):

> When qna maker matches with multiple questions it responses with do you mean and list of questions?

If the user query is too generic, which would match with equal likelihood with multiple answers.

> Is it possible to add alias for these questions

You can try to add the user query as [an alternate question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/best-practices#add-alternate-questions), which could help improve the confidence score of a particular response to a user query.